# Cakephp 3 adding slash to end of URL

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I wanted to ask, how can I use routes or Html link function or use another strategy to add `/` at end of url?
I would like to have `www.myurl/content/` not `www.myurl/content`.

Is this possible?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an Apache webserver, you could use mod_rewrite. All you need is the following lines in a .htaccess file, which is placed in the root directory.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

This is a good way to force your requested URL rule.

Comment: now i have:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
    RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
Dont work.